# Is there a way to write over the python code after the interpretation?

Tags: python

This may be a dumb question, but I want to add a line at the very start of the code like

> print 'previous runtime' time.time()-tic

Is there a way to do it? Or can I somehow get the previous runtime other than keeping a logfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to disagree with the accepted answer. You can edit Python code during interpretation for future runtime use. The file itself isn't locked during execution and can be edited by itself. Try this simple example named test.py:

```
def main():
    with open('test.py','a') as me:
        me.write('    print "test"\n')

if __name__== '__main__':
    main()
```

Every time you run this, it will add an additional "print test" at the end of the file and next runtime will execute the modified code.

Your example is more complex, but I see no reason why you couldn't insert a variable with the last runtime and call it for a print.

```
me.write('last_runtime = {0}'.format(time.time())
```

I will say that while this is possible it's probably(read 'almost certainly') not the best approach. It would be much easier to just have a last_run.pickle and pickle dump a datetime object or whatever to save the last runtime (overwriting the previous last runtime). Then have your code reference this reference file.

While you CAN edit your code from your code, the only reason I can imagine for doing it this way is if you 100% need everything for your program in one file (which seems an unlikely requirement). Otherwise best to save your data somewhere and reference it.

Comment: I did not want to hastily accept an answer this time. (You know, when someone says you can't do it, you don't test it:) ) I tried to reproduce your code. It gives no error but it also does not edit the code file.

Comment: The very simplistic proof of concept provided would require your file being named test.py and to be executed from its own directory since no path information was supplied in the script to where test.py is. If you did both of those things and it still isn't working let me know and provide some system info (I tested in python 2.7 on a linux system)

Comment: I'll check again, when I finally have access to my computer. Ty

Answer (score 1):

No. It wouldn't be possible unless written somewhere. Simple reason is that once the python process ends, GC cleans up everything.

Comment: So, I can't open it as a text file while on the run, save it and finish the process?